# subdomains redirecting to owncloud

Tags: redirect, nginx, subdomain, owncloud

I can't get rid of this problem.

Subdomains that are configured in nginx/sites-available redirect to the corresponding folder but non-existent subdomains always redirect to owncloud and want to be added as a trustworthy domain to my owncloud installation.

https://devel.kazuto.de redirects to the right content, hence the 403.

https://loremipsum.kazuto.de redirects to owncloud.

here's my configuration:

```
upstream php-handler {
    #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
     server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name cloud.kazuto.de www.cloud.kazuto.de;

    return 301 https://cloud.kazuto.de$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name cloud.kazuto.de;

    root /var/www/kazuto.de/cloud/htdocs;

    error_log /var/www/kazuto.de/logs/cloud.kazuto.de_error.log;
    access_log /var/www/kazuto.de/logs/cloud.kazuto.de_access.log;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers '';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    resolver 127.0.0.1;

    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
    add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;


    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

        # With php5-cgi alone:
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location = /.well-known/carddav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
    }

    location = /.well-known/caldav {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge { }

    location ^~ / {

        # set max upload size
        client_max_body_size 512M;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        # Disable gzip to avoid the removal of the ETag header
        gzip off;

        # Uncomment if your server is build with the ngx_pagespeed module
        # This module is currently not supported.
        #pagespeed off;

        error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
        error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

        location / {
            rewrite ^ /index.php$uri;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+|core/templates/40[34])\.php(?:$|/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
            #Avoid sending the security headers twice
            fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
            fastcgi_param front_controller_active true;
            fastcgi_pass php-handler;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
            try_files $uri/ =404;
            index index.php;
        }

        # Adding the cache control header for js and css files
        # Make sure it is BELOW the PHP block
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200";
            # Add headers to serve security related headers  (It is intended
            # to have those duplicated to the ones above)
            # Before enabling Strict-Transport-Security headers please read
            # into this topic first.
            # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000;
            # includeSubDomains; preload;";
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
            add_header X-Download-Options noopen;
            add_header X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies none;
            # Optional: Don't log access to assets
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~* \.(?:svg|gif|png|html|ttf|woff|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$uri$is_args$args;
            # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
            access_log off;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Non-existent sub domains will use the default domain. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Comment: But the default domain is not located in the owncloud directory. My default domain is kazuto.de and the folder contains workpress, not owncloud.

`kazuto.de = /var/www/kazuto.de/htdocs`
`owncloud.kazuto.de = /var/www/kazuto.de/owncloud`

Comment: So the other `server` block contains a `listen 443 ssl https2 default_domain;` statement?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Guess I have to add this :D `nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "default_domain" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/kazuto.de:16` which is `listen 443 ssl http2 default_domain;`

Comment: Sorry, typo, I meant to write `default_server` not `default_domain`.

Comment: I've had it at `80 default_server` but not at `443 ssl http2 default_server` ^^